# KQL Render columnchart ignoring ycolumns and ysplit properties

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, azure-sentinel

I'm trying to create an KQL query that visualizes the ten most frequently seen incidents in a time period.
In this visualization I want to display **both** the percentage of the total that was closed by classification X (same for Y and Z) **and** the actual amount of tickets again per classification, either with a ysplit=axes or ysplit=panels but KQL is ignoring both the ycolumns and ysplit properties. Individually both charts render perfectly fine, but ideally I'd avoid needing to run two queries.

My current query:

```
let offset = -1;
let data = 
SecurityIncident
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by IncidentNumber
| where Status =~ "Closed"
| where Severity != "Informational"
| where TimeGenerated between (startofmonth(now(), offset) .. endofmonth(now(), offset));
data
| join kind=fullouter (
    data
    | summarize ClosureCount = count() by Title, ClassificationReason)
    on Title, ClassificationReason
        | join kind=fullouter (
        data
        | summarize TotalCount = count() by Title)
        on Title  
| extend percentage = (todouble(ClosureCount)/todouble(TotalCount))*100
| summarize ClosureDistribution = make_set(
                                    bag_pack(
                                                "Closure reason",
                                                ClassificationReason,
                                                "Count",
                                                ClosureCount,
                                                "Percentage",
                                                (todouble(ClosureCount)/todouble(TotalCount))*100
                                    ),100) by Title, TotalCount
| sort by TotalCount, Title desc 
| take 10
| project-away TotalCount
| mv-expand ClosureDistribution
| extend Reason = iif(isnotempty(tostring(ClosureDistribution.["Closure reason"])), tostring(ClosureDistribution.["Closure reason"]), "Defender AutoClosed"),
         Percentage = toreal(ClosureDistribution.["Percentage"]),
         Amount = toreal(ClosureDistribution.["Count"])
| project-keep Reason, Title, Percentage, Amount
| render columnchart with (ycolumns=Amount, Percentage, ysplit=panels)
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROitv.png)
Unfortunately this does not output two different columncharts, one for the % distribution and one for the amount distribution. It only renders one with the percentage as Y axis, even when I remove the Percentage from the ycolumns property in the render statement.
I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I haven't been able to find a fix for this so any help would be appreciated!